# SQL Server did not install with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2015 Community but SQL Server Express did not install with it - why?

Before I installed VS 2015 Update 1 and everything was perfect but now SQL Server Express did not get installed.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install SQL server individually. visual studio package never have SQL server with them.

You can download SQL SERVER 2012 Express: https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29062

> Download **SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015** to build SQL Server relational databases, Azure SQL databases, Integration Services packages, Analysis Services data models, and Reporting Services reports.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much muhammad